# "Unexpected token ." when using optional chaning "?." syntax when running mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I'm playing around with TS and encountered an error when trying to run a test for my code.
I have a the following piece of code:

```
return this._map.get(y)?.get(x)
```

When I run the code for browser, everything works fine. When I run a test using `mocha`, however, it throws an error :

```
        return this._map.get(y)?.get(x);        
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

From what I managed to read, I'm supposed to configure `tsc` differently for NodeJS environment for things to work, but I was under the impression it was more about module resolution than syntax. Could it be that I need to upgrade to any specific NodeJS version? I've tried Node 10 through 13 but none worked.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Optional chaining is still behind a flag in Node.js v13. It isn't anymore in the latest Node.js (v14.9.0), though it still was in v14.4.0, so it got deflagged somewhere between those two.

Either update to the latest, or to enable it in v13 and earlier versions of v14:

```
node --harmony-optional-chaining ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this in Node 12 with TypeScript by changing my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": ["ES2019"],
  "module": "es2015",
  "target": "ES2019",
  ...
}
```

I was getting this error when my `target` was `"esnext"`.  After I changed to `"ES2019"` it worked just fine in Node 12. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining was added in **ES2020**, which isn't supported by *Node* yet. So if your <kbd>target</kbd> compile option is **ES2020** or **ESNext**, then TypeScript compiler will see an optional chaining operator and leave it alone.

If your target is **ES2019** or further back then typescript will transpile the feature into something that *Node* will understand. something like:

```
const attributeScores = (_a = apiResponse === null || apiResponse === void 0 ? void 0 ...
```

Source : [Syntax Error with Optional Chaining in Typescript 3.7](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1283#issuecomment-592711385)